# Convert byte[] to String and back

Tags: java, arrays, pdf

I'm trying to save content of a pdf file in a json and thought of saving the pdf as String value converted from byte[].

```
    byte[] byteArray = feature.convertPdfToByteArray(Paths.get("path.pdf"));

    String byteString = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 

    byte[] newByteArray = byteString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 

    String secondString = new String(newByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


    System.out.println(secondString.equals(byteString));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(byteArray, newByteArray));
    System.out.println(byteArray.length + " vs " + newByteArray.length);
```

The result of the above code is as follows:

```
true
false
421371 vs 760998
```

The two `String`'s are equal while the two `byte[]`s are not. Why is that and how to correctly convert/save a pdf inside a json?

Comment: JSON is not the appropriate format for binary content (like files). You should propably use something like base64 to create a string out of your PDF and store that in your JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the wrong charset when reading from the PDF file.

For example, the character `é` (`e` with acute) does not exists in ISO-8859-1 :

```
byte[] byteArray = "é".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
String byteString = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] newByteArray = byteString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String secondString = new String(newByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println(secondString.equals(byteString));
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(byteArray, newByteArray));
System.out.println(byteArray.length + " vs " + newByteArray.length);
```

**Output** :

```
true
false
1 vs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is that

If the `byteArray` indeed contains a PDF, it most likely is not valid UTF-8. Thus, wherever

```
String byteString = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

stumbles over a byte sequence which is not valid UTF-8, it will replace that by a Unicode replacement character. I.e. this line damages your data, most likely beyond repair. So the following

```
byte[] newByteArray = byteString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

does not result in the original byte array but instead a damaged version of it.

---

The `newByteArray`, on the other hand, is the result of UTF-8 encoding a given string, `byteString`. Thus, `newByteArray` is valid UTF-8 and

```
String secondString = new String(newByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

does not need to replace anything outside the UTF-8 mappings, in particular `byteString` and `secondString` are equal.

#### how to correctly convert/save a pdf inside a json?

As @mammago explained in his comment,

> JSON is not the appropriate format for binary content (like files). You should propably use something like base64 to create a string out of your PDF and store that in your JSON object.